# to find the opinion of a sentence as positive or negative

Tags: python, python-2.7, pos-tagger, senti-wordnet

i need to find the opinion of certain reviews given in websites. i am using sentiwordnet for this. i first send the file containing all the reviews to POS Tagger.

```
tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(line) #tokenization for line in file
tagged=nltk.pos_tag(tokens) #for POSTagging
print tagged
```

Is there any other accurate way of tokenizing which considers not good as 1 word other than considering it as 2 separate words.

Now i have to give postive and negative score to the tokenized words and then calculate the total score. Is there any function in sentiwordnet for this. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See First Extract Adverbs and Adjectives from review
for example:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
import csv

para = "What can I say about this place. The staff of the restaurant is nice and the eggplant is not bad. Apart from that, very uninspired food, lack of atmosphere and too expensive. I am a staunch vegetarian and was sorely dissapointed with the veggie options on the menu. Will be the last time I visit, I recommend others to avoid"

sentense = word_tokenize(para)
word_features = []

for i,j in nltk.pos_tag(sentense):
    if j in ['JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS']: 
        word_features.append(i)

rating = 0

for i in word_features:
    with open('words.txt', 'rt') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if i == row[0]:
                print i, row[1]
                if row[1] == 'pos':
                    rating = rating + 1
                elif row[1] == 'neg':
                    rating = rating - 1
print  rating
```

Now you must have a external csv file in which you should have positive and negative words

like : 
wrinkle,neg
wrinkled,neg
wrinkles,neg
masterfully,pos
masterpiece,pos
masterpieces,pos

Working of the above script as follows:

1 . read sentence
2 . extract adverb and adjectives
3 . compare to CVS for positive and negative words
4 . and then rate the sentence

Result of above script is :

```
nice pos  
bad neg  
expensive neg  
sorely neg  
-2
```

change result as per your need. 
and sorry for my english :P

Comment: Thankyou. but we are using huge data to be classifled as positive and negative words which we cant pass manually. so i am using sentiwordnet for this. i will be glad if there is any code for obtaining the positive and negative score of each sentence.

Comment: This is just an example @THIRTHA, I am also using this for bulk data!!

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)